# What If a processes don't fit in memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

If processes don’t fit in memory, What moves them in and out of memory to run?
this question is based on Operating System Memory management theory.

I have checked about the purpose of memory management unit. Is this related to swapping?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what swapping is about. If parts of the memory for a process isn't needed it can be swapped out to a file. And later when it's needed again it can be swapped into primary memory again (possible causing some other process to be swapped out).

Comment: yes.i got that. should study more about paging and virtual memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system will use a memory management technique called virtual memory.

This is when a computer compensates for shortages of physical memory by temporarily transferring pages (segments of memory) of data from RAM to backing store. RAM is much faster than secondary storage and when a computer needs to use secondary storage over primary the user will feel the computer running slower.

The operating systems virtual memory manager is responsible for managing this. It will use techniques such as placing pages that have not been referenced for in a while into secondary memory (you hard disk for example) and if a page in secondary storage is required it will move the page from secondary to primary memory.

Another point is that most modern apps will page themselves, such as when they are minimised for example, to reduce the amount of memory they're using for other applications running.

Comment: thank you @Alfie . Should research about virtual memory and paging